# Can I set text box to readonly when using Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: .net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following  tag with a Html.TextBoxFor expression and I want the contents to be read only, is this possible?

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Events.Subscribed[i].Action)%>
```

Comment: > [Here is n You can see. how to create read only textbox in MVC](http://www.codeshower.blogspot.in/2012/09/mvc-how-to-create-readonly-textbox-in.html)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Updated for modern versions of .NET per @1c1cle's suggestion in a comment:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.SomeFieldName, new {{"readonly", "true"}}) %>
```

Do realize that this is not a "secure" way to do this as somebody can inject javascript to change this.

Something to be aware of is that if you set that `readonly` value to `false`, you actually won't see any change in behavior! So if you need to drive this based on a variable, you cannot simply plug that variable in there. Instead you need to use conditional logic to simply not pass that `readonly` attribute in.

Here is an untested suggestion for how to do this (if there's a problem with this, you can always do an if/else):

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.SomeFieldName, shouldBeReadOnlyBoolean ? new {{"readonly", "true"}} : null) %>
```

Comment: new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"readonly", "false "}} and new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"readonly", "anything"}} provide the same results.

Answer (score 129):

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Events.Subscribed[i].Action, new { @readonly = true })%>
```

Comment: this is correct, but @readonly=false provides the same result for me. Thus, it's the value of readonly that decides the functionality, but the existence of the attribute itself.

Comment: is there any way to overcome this? Basically I want to dynamically assign @readonly = false or true on some other variables (stupid requirements)

Answer (score 46):

Use the following:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Whatever, new {@readonly = "readonly"})
```

If you want to assign a class to it you could do it the same way , by adding the 
     @class = ""
 property. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 16):

To make it read only

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Total, new {@class ="form-control", @readonly="true"})
```

To diable

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Total, new {@class ="form-control", @disabled="true"})
```

Answer (score 7):

The following snippet worked for me.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Crown, new { id = "", @style = "padding-left:5px", @readonly = "true" })
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Events.Subscribed[i].Action, new {readonly=true})%>
```

Answer (score 6):

This work for me...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RIF, new { value = @Model.RIF, @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: I know it's very late but for people reading this later:
there is no need for this  "value = @Model.RIF"

.Net Framework do this for you. if Model.RIF has value, the value assigned to input text box.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Events.Subscribed[i].Action, new { @autocomplete = "off", @readonly=true})%>
```

This is how you set multiple properties

Answer (score 2):

An other possibility :

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.SomeFieldName, new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"disabled", "true"}}) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the example of @Hunter, in the new { .. } part, add readonly = true, I think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the answer of Brain Mains is almost correct:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RIF, new { value = @Model.RIF, @readonly = true })
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have to apply your custom class you can use

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Birthday,   new Dictionary<string, object>() { {"readonly", "true"}, {"class", "commonField"} } )
```

Where are

**commonField** is CSS class

and **Birthday** could be string field that you probably can use to keep `jQuery Datapicker` date :)

```
<script>
             $(function () {
                 $("#Birthday").datepicker({

                 });
             });
  </script>
```

That's a real life example.

Answer (score 1):

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IdUsuario, new { @Value = "" + User.Identity.GetUserId() + "", @disabled = "true" })

@disabled = "true"
```

Work very well

Answer (score 1):

You can also disabled TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.day, null, new { @class = "form-control success" ,@disabled="disabled" })
```

Comment: I would not advise this. I just discovered that by disabling the field, it makes it so that the model can't get the value when you trigger an action result.

Answer (score 0):

By setting readonly attribute to either true or false is not going to work in most browsers, I have done it as below, when the mode of the page is "reload", I've not included "readonly" attribute.

```
@if(Model.Mode.Equals("edit")){
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Content.Data, new { id = "modEditor", @readonly = moduleEditModel.Content.ReadOnly, @style = "width:99%; height:360px;" })
}
@if (Model.Mode.Equals("reload")){
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => Model.Content.Data, new { id = "modEditor", @style = "width:99%; height:360px;" })}
```