# How do I make an Html.TextBox either read-only or invisible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Complete n00b to MVC.  I've been asked to knock up a quick contact management system for my running club.  It's all working ok, based on the MVC Contact Manager template:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/contact-manager/iteration-1-create-the-application-cs

I've adapted this to link to the club's SQL Server Membership database.  However, it exposes the Primary Key of the Member table on the Edit form.  I don't mind it being visible but it **MUST** be read-only (though it would be better if it were not visible).

The markup generated for the View is

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID") %>
```

I've tried adding attributes such as read-only, visible etc. but though it compiles, it blows up when it's rendered.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID"); Visible = false %>
```

I'm pretty sure this can be done but I have run out of Google hits on this!

Thanks

Edward

Comment: I guess, a more appropriate element is `Html.Hidden`. `TextBox` is for user input. That's clearly not what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set text box to readonly when using Html.TextBoxFor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539069/can-i-set-text-box-to-readonly-when-using-html-textboxfor)

Comment: @DGibbs, he's not using `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: @AndreiV It's the same concept for both

Comment: I am a doofus - I put the new { @readonly = "readonly" } outside the parentheses, not inside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable it,so that it can't be editable:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", "", new {@disabled="disabled"}) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the HTML properties and set the input as `readonly`. This will add the appropriate HTML markup in order to make the text box read only:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", "", new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

This method uses the [Html.TextBox(String, Object, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload, with the first parameter being the name of the input, the second being the value and the third the dictionary containing the HTML properties.

EDIT: As DGibbs pointed out, `readonly` is a reserved keyword and must be preceded by `@`. However, I find it better to create a `Dictionary` object that contains the HTML properties. This is also what the MVC prefers since it converts all the `object`s into `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> htmlProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
htmlProperties.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

You can then just specify it as the third parameter, using the [Html.TextBox(String, Object, IDictionary)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505258%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("ID", "", htmlProperties) %>
```

Comment: `readonly` is a reserved keyword. There's no way this would work. It needs to be `@readonly = "readonly"`.

Comment: @DGibbs, thanks. I forget about reserved keywords all the time... I'm always using dictionaries to pass HTML properties in part to avoid these situations. I guess it turns into a habit and I forget why I'm doing it...