# Web Accessibility failing on "Missing form label"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As part of a web accessibility exercise, our site is being picked up for some missing form labels

The text areas are elements we do not wish to have visible labels against (the site is ASP.NET MVC/Razor using jQuery)

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.UserInput.FeedbackContent)
```

Is the correct approach is this scenario to create a corresponding LabelFor and hide it?

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserInput.FeedbackContent, new {@class = 'hidden'})
```

Or is there a way within the TextAreaFor to create a hidden label?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is the correct approach is this scenario to create a corresponding LabelFor and hide it?

Not if you hide it via `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, as those will [make screenreaders ignore it as well](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#note-on-hiding-elements).

There *are* CSS tricks you could use to hide it only visually, but instead, consider using the [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#using-aria-label) attribute on the text area itself. In HTML this would be:

```html
<textarea ... aria-label="Label for the text area" ...>
```

I don't use Asp.Net-MVC, but I believe you do that like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.UserInput.FeedbackContent, new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"aria-label", "Label for the text area"}});
```

Comment: Thanks very much - so not being too familiar with ASP MVC/Razor, how would I set that attribute through @Html.TextAreaFor? Would it be new{@attribute = "aria_label = 'Label for the text area'"}

Comment: @Mike: Heh, I was just researching that and adding it to the answer (see above, you may have to hit Refresh). I based that on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2539117/157247) about an unrelated attribute.