# How to turn HTML TextBoxFor into Labels in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form, I would like where I have `Html.TextBoxFor` into labels is this possible?

```
@* title *@
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4">Song Title</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @foreach (var t in Model.OriginalWork.AlternativeTitles)
                 {<label class="control-label text-muted">@t.Title</label>
                 }
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Alternative Titles *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalWork.AlternativeTitles, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="tag-container tags col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: AlternateTitles">
                        @foreach (var t in Model.OriginalWork.AlternativeTitles)
                    {<span class="tm-tag tm-tag-info" data-bind="hidden: IsDeleted">
                            @t.Title
                        </span>
                }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        @* Duration *@
        <div class="form-group mbn">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 pull-left hidden-sm" for="DurationMinutes">Duration</label>
            <div class="col-md-1 mb15">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalWork.DurationMins, new { @class = "control-label pull-left hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OriginalWork.DurationMins, new { @class = "form-control isDisabled", placeholder = "Mins...", data_bind = "value: DurationMins" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OriginalWork.DurationMins, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 mb15">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalWork.DurationSecs, new { @class = "control-label pull-left hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OriginalWork.DurationSecs, new { @class = "form-control isDisabled", placeholder = "Secs...", data_bind = "value: DurationSecs" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OriginalWork.DurationSecs, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @* Performing Artists *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalWork.PerformingArtistNames, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="tag-container tags col-md-12" data-bind="foreach: PerformingArtistNames">
                        @foreach (var t in Model.OriginalWork.PerformingArtistNames)
                    {<span class="tm-tag tm-tag-info" data-bind="hidden: IsDeleted">
                            @t.Firstname @t.Lastname
                        </span>
                }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @* remix and samples *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalWork.IsRemix, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
                    <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OriginalWork.IsRemix, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <label for="IsRemixYes">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 pull-left">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OriginalWork.IsRemix, false, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <label for="IsRemixNo">No</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*Contains Sample Radio Button*@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalWork.ContainsSample, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="admin-form theme-primary">
                    <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 mr10 pull-left">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OriginalWork.ContainsSample, true, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <label for="ContainsSampleYes">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio-custom radio-primary mt10 pull-left">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OriginalWork.ContainsSample, false, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <label for="ContainsSampleNo">No</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @* ISWC *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OriginalWork.Iswc, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OriginalWork.Iswc, new { @class = "form-control  isDisabled", placeholder = "ISWC", data_bind = "value: Iswc" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OriginalWork.Iswc, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: it looks like you already have labels as well as text boxes. can you give more detail on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DarthTommy Its a form so I have labels but where the TextBoxes are I would like them to be labels also.

Comment: Why would you want to turn a `TextBoxFor` into a Label? what's wrong with `LabelFor`? This question is...odd?

Comment: I get that but can you explain why you want to do that? What are the details of your current task/job

Comment: It's probably worth noting that all `TextBoxFor` does is output a html `<input type="textbox"/>` with some bells an whistles. There is nothing to stop you output the HTML yourself and/or manipulating this as you see fit. Still nto sure what your actually asking though...

Comment: @Liam I have tried LabelFor but it doesnt work.

Comment: So you've tried LabelFor and it didn't output a label?! o_O This question makes no sense. Please try and be clear on what you want, why, what you've tried, etc etc

Comment: The form is a read only, so basically I dont want the inputs to be editable. I can add a class to disable the form, but I wanted to do it a little neater using razor.

Comment: I think you want `disabled` and or `readonly` attributes or for that matter just print the output `@Model.Value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set text box to readonly when using Html.TextBoxFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539069/can-i-set-text-box-to-readonly-when-using-html-textboxfor)

Comment: I will try the `@Model.Value`

Comment: `@Model.Value` does not seem to work either.

Comment: have you tried @Html.DisplayFor

Comment: @DarthTommy thanks that has worked for the text box. I am just trying the radio buttons.

Comment: Is there a way to have a label instead of a radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable your radio button, assuming you're using razor syntax, you can use:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SomeModelItem, "false")
```

And this should put you on the right track.